# Python/Pandas: How to merge rows based on other column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a table of work experience data. The problem I'm facing is some people's work experiences have overlapping dates (ie. See rows 240, 241 & 242, 243) where the start date occurs before end date of the previous job. This causes an overstatement of the total years of experience. For purposes of calculating total years of experience, how can I get total years of work experience without double counting overlapping jobs like example shown.

I initially summed the position tenure for each person to get the total years of experience but that doesn't account for double counting.

[image]

Comment: you can do the `groupby` on `person_id` and then get the min(start_date) and max(end_date), the `start_date` and the `end_date` have to be datetime type. Then get the difference between the two dates. You could convert the value into days and divide by 365 to get the exact float value in years.

Comment: @Priya I thought of this but there are periods where people don't have a job (or haven't updated their linkedin) so it would over estimate total years of experience in some cases and under estimate in other cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

Input data:

```
>>> df
    start_date   end_date
237 2005-01-01 2007-12-01
238 2008-01-01 2012-09-01
239 2012-09-01 2013-07-01
240 2013-07-01 2016-05-01
241 2014-06-01 2016-05-01
242 2016-05-01 2019-10-01
243 2018-01-01 2019-10-01
244 2020-05-01 2021-08-03
```

First compute the diff between `end_date` and `start_date`:

```
df['diff1'] = df['end_date'] - df['start_date']
print(df)

    start_date   end_date     diff1
237 2005-01-01 2007-12-01 1064 days
238 2008-01-01 2012-09-01 1705 days
239 2012-09-01 2013-07-01  303 days
240 2013-07-01 2016-05-01 1035 days
241 2014-06-01 2016-05-01  700 days
242 2016-05-01 2019-10-01 1248 days
243 2018-01-01 2019-10-01  638 days
244 2020-05-01 2021-08-03  459 days
```

Now, subtract `start_date` and `end_date - 1` only if the start date occurs before end date of the previous row:

```
df['diff2'] = (df['start_date'] - df['end_date'].shift()) \
                  .mul(df['start_date'].le(df['end_date'].shift()))
print(df)

  start_date   end_date     diff1     diff2
0 2005-01-01 2007-12-01 1064 days       NaT
1 2008-01-01 2012-09-01 1705 days    0 days
2 2012-09-01 2013-07-01  303 days    0 days
3 2013-07-01 2016-05-01 1035 days    0 days
4 2014-06-01 2016-05-01  700 days -700 days
5 2016-05-01 2019-10-01 1248 days    0 days
6 2018-01-01 2019-10-01  638 days -638 days
7 2020-05-01 2021-08-03  459 days    0 days
```

Finally, add the two `diffX` columns:

```
df['real'] = df[['diff1', 'diff2']].sum(axis=1)
print(df)

  start_date   end_date     diff1     diff2      real
0 2005-01-01 2007-12-01 1064 days       NaT 1064 days
1 2008-01-01 2012-09-01 1705 days    0 days 1705 days
2 2012-09-01 2013-07-01  303 days    0 days  303 days
3 2013-07-01 2016-05-01 1035 days    0 days 1035 days
4 2014-06-01 2016-05-01  700 days -700 days    0 days
5 2016-05-01 2019-10-01 1248 days    0 days 1248 days
6 2018-01-01 2019-10-01  638 days -638 days    0 days
7 2020-05-01 2021-08-03  459 days    0 days  459 days
```

The real experience is `df['real'].sum().days / 365`, almost 16 years instead of 19.5 years. You can put this code into a function and call it when `apply` after `groupby` on `person_id`.

> How would I create a function that can be used with the apply method?

```
def total_xp_years(df):
    diff1 = df['end_date'] - df['start_date']
    diff2 = df['start_date'] - df['end_date'].shift()
    diff2 *= df['start_date'].le(df['end_date'].shift())
    return (diff1.sum() + diff2.sum()).days / 365

dfxp = df.groupby('person_id').apply(total_xp_years)
```

Comment: How would I create a function that can be used with the apply method?

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check it please?

Comment: It works but not quite how I would like. I managed to fix it via a for loop and pd.merge() but still using the initial code you provided. Thanks